# Generic class inheritance in Swift - Compile error

Tags: swift, generics, inheritance

The following Swift code does not compile:

```
class A<T:Codable> {

}

class C<T: Codable> : A<T: Codable> { //Expected '>' to complete generic argument list

}
```

I get the following error:

> "Expected '>' to complete generic argument list"

Please help.

Comment: Just `class C<T: Codable> : A<T> { ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
class A<T:Codable> {

} 
class C<T: Codable> : A<T> {

}
```

---

When you do `class A<T:Codable>` with `C<T:Codable>`  that means the object inside `<>` conforms to `Codable` so when you make it as a parent class you put the name of the object to be used without redundantly adding `: Codable`

Comment: So easy... Thank you